# the best overloaded method match for x has some invalid arguments (two more errors)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Receiving three errors when I am trying to add a function that saves something to my database, using Linq to SQL.

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add(Egen_projekt.Personer)'
>   has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'Egen_projekt.Person' to
>   'Egen_projekt.Personer'
>
> No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments

The send function:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string one = txt1.Text;
        string two = txt2.Text;
        db.Personer.Add(txt1.Text, txt2.Text);
        db.SaveChanges();

}
```

Web form:

```
<form method="post">
 Name: &nbsp;<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1"></asp:TextBox>
 <br />
 Twitter link: &nbsp;<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="Button1_Click" /></form>
```

Entity framework model:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HXw1.png

Anything I missed?

Comment: What's not clear about the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `db.Personer.Add()` expects you to pass in an object of type `Personer` but you are passing in two strings. You need to create a new `Personer` object, set any properties you want, then pass that to `db.Personer.Add()`

Comment: Why was this downvoted? You may not have like his question, but my answer was correct and accepted